# Why is Preview grayed out in the designer view of Android Studio?

Tags: android-layout, listview, android-fragments

I am trying to add some text fields and a button from the design tab, but the preview mode is grayed out. However, in text mode preview is enabled.

[image: Screenshot showing that Preview is grayed out]

Comment: I had the same problem just restarting android studio fixed it